# Regular Expression (regex, regexp) for username

Tags: javascript

[Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mji8.jpg)
[Code Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlhmc.jpg)
***(Update)***: I added the instructions and code as images instead. I tried the suggestions and they did not go through. ***(Update)***

This is my first ever question on here. Been using stack for advice but im stumped this time. I am new to regular expressions and am stuck on this assignment.

The question is as follows:

"write a regex test such that...

- Only a username that has alphanumeric characters (lower and upper case letters
- Numbers allowed only - (no spaces, no underscores)
- Has at minimum 2 characters
- Has a number as the final character (such as 'Jason1') is accepted via the form

We are working with this code here...
function validate() {
  let inputStr = document.getElementById("username").value;

//  const myReg = // Uncomment this line and add your regular expression literal here

if (myReg.test(inputStr)) 
    alert("Username accepted");
  else
    alert("Username must contain only alphanumeric characters, contain a mininum of two characters, and end with a digit.");
}

So we have to take out the Uncomment and hopefully it matches the myReg.test. 
I tried my best by doing /^[a-z\d][5.12]$/i and /^[a-z\d+?]$/i
But i am completely off! How should it look like?

Comment: Please elaborate on "has at minimum 2 characters". Is "a45" a valid username? Is "a4" a valid username?

Comment: I am assuming `/[a-z0-9]+\d/i`, but your updated description makes even less sense to me than the original - username should be alphanumeric, but then numbers allowed only?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be this ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Y7hJcQ/4)):

```regex
/[A-z0-9]+\d/
```

Let me explain.

You can use `[]` to create lists of allowed characters (as in, each `[]` will match a single character, but any one in the list). Usually, I would use `\w`, but this is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, and the question stipulates no underscores (you can save space by doing `A` to `z`, since capitals are before lower-case in unicode).

`{}` is used to specify an amount of a character that must match. So, you could say `a{3,6}`, and that would mean that only between three and six `a`s would match. You can omit the last index (`a{3,}`) to say *at least this many matches*, or *between `n` and unlimited* times. Using this, you can match "at least one" with `{1,}`. This is then shortened to the equivalent `+`.

Finally, we say that the regex must have a digit `\d` at the end.

The "minimum length of two" is covered by requiring at least one of any accepted character with a digit at the end. One plus one is two.

Comment: `[A-z]` is not equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]`. The range 65(A)-122(z) includes symbols like e.g. `[` or `_`.

Comment: Ah, good point. I guess I never thought hard enough about what's in that range. Should probably go with something like `/[a-z0-9]+\d/i`.

Comment: more likely [A-Za-z0-9] to include the uppercase letters too

Comment: @B.Go that’s what the `i` flag is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
  let inputStr = document.getElementById("username").value;

 const myReg = /^[a-z0-9]{1,}[0-9]$/igm

  if (myReg.test(inputStr)) 
    alert("Username accepted");
  else
    alert("Username must contain only alphanumeric characters, contain a minimum of two characters, and end with a digit.");
}
```

This link will make you understand all the regex https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/240